# Artifactory does not find license I added to the jar

Tags: maven, licensing, artifactory

I want to add a license file to my Maven project. According to the Maven standard, it should be in the root folder of the project with the name LICENSE.txt.

I did that and published the jar to Artifactory. I added a new license type in Artifactory with my company name and the proper search regex.

For some reason, Artifactory **Scan** does not find it. If I do "**Search Archive License File**", the file is found and I can see my license text. But the auto scan does not work.

I even tried to put the Apache 2.0 license text knowing that this one is already in the list of pre-defined licenses, no luck.

I also tried adding the license text in the POM file. Again no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try putting the LICENSE.txt file under META-INF/? That's where I usually see it.

Comment: I tried that. The Scan option does not find the file. The Search does find it. However, the goal is for Artifactory to find it automatically during the scan. So that does not solve the original problem,

Comment: @FrançoisGuertin same problem for me, have you found a solution ?